# Ubable to add an Exchange Account in android 4.0 Enumator

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am trying to add event in Android 4.0 emulator for that i have to add an Exchange account.
this is what i am getting in response.

[image: response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself just had to

Enter `m.google.com` as the server address.
and select the `SSL` option during setup.